# Weak convergence(i.e convergence in distribution) of first order statistics # problem 1.1(ch 6) of "Intermediate course in Probability" by Allan Gut

Tags: weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

For each $n = 1, 2, ....$, suppose that $X_n$ is a continuous random variable with density
$$\hspace{10mm}\mathrm{f}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(1+x)e^{-x},  & \text{if $x \ge 0$ } \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x\le 0$}
\end{cases}$$
Set $Y_n$=min{$X_1,X_2,....X_n$}. Does n$\cdot$$Y_n$ converges in distribution as n$\to \infty $ ?
What will be the limiting distribution of n$\cdot$$Y_n$?
Attept:
I was tryng to find the distribution of n$\cdot$$Y_n$. But it became too complicated.
How should I proceed here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find a distribution function of $nY_n$.\

$P(nY_n \leq t) = 1 - P(min \{ X_1, ..., X_n \} > \frac{t}{n}) = 1 - P(X_1 > \frac{t}{n})\cdot ... \cdot P(X_n > \frac{t}{n})$

We can calculate the tail of the random variable $X_1$ (and all of the variables because I suppose that they are i.i.d).

$P(X_1 > \frac{t}{n}) = \int_{\frac{t}{n}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}(1+x) \exp (-x) dx$.

Now, try to do this integral by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint. Now Is the limiting distribution degenerate at t=0? i.e $P(Z=0)=1$ where n$\cdot$$Y_n$ $\to Z$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: We can say that $F(t) = 0$ for $t <= 0$. It suffices main assumption of the cumulative distribution function because $\lim_{t \rightarrow - \infty} F(t) = 0$ For the rest of the $\mathbb{R}$ we have to calculate this integral above.